# Cómo mantener las dimensiones de un elemento hijo?

Tags: html, css, scale

Cómo puedo mantener las dimensiones de un elemento hijo, al escalar las dimensiones de su elemento padre?

```
  <div class="parent">
     <h1 class="child">Hola mundo</h1>
  <div>

 .parent{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform:scale(5);
  background:"red";
}   

.child{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 font-size:20px; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar el `transform` también al hijo con un valor inverso al del padre.

Si el padre escala en 5 unidades entonces el hijo escala 5 unidades a la inversa 1/5 = 0.2.

```css
 .parent{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
  transform: scale(5);
}   

.child{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 font-size:20px; 
 transform: scale(0.2);
 }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
     <h1 class="child">Hola mundo</h1>
 <div>
```